# HTML5 Local Storage URL Prefix

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, local-storage

I am using local storage for self-educational purposes and checking an checkbox if it is checked and closing the Bootstrap Modal.

```
$( "#olurmu" ).click(function() {
    var isaret = document.getElementById("olurmu");
    localStorage.setItem("olurmu", isaret.checked);
});

function isaretKontrol() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("olurmu"))
    {
        var evet = localStorage.getItem("olurmu");
        document.getElementById("olurmu").checked = evet;
    }
}
```

The problem is localSotrage is working on www.mydomain.com but the thing is it is not working when i go to www.mydomain.com/myarticle. Is there any way store the localstorage file all through my domain?

Comment: localStorage should be available through domain. Don't you mix up www/non-www domains?

Comment: BTW, your checking code is wrong. LS always store strings and boolean `false` will become string `"false"` and will be considered `true` when you check it.

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite your code like this:

```
$("#olurmu").click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem("olurmu", this.checked ? "1" : "");
});

function isaretKontrol() {
    var evet = localStorage.getItem("olurmu") ? true : false;
    document.getElementById("olurmu").checked = evet;
}
```

`localStorage` store only strings, so storing boolean to it would result in string representation of that boolean. That why we should store strings. The only falsy string is empty one (`""`).

Comment: Thanks for advice and correction. Still not working all-through domain.

Comment: @Cromwell, how did you check it? Just open console and check `localStorage.getItem('olurmu')`

Comment: i noticed that main reason of bug is about the jQuery that i have been using via Google CDN. Somehow it is not delivering everytime i load the page. I was so focused on localStorage, because i have never worked it before, i didnt even think that source of the error is jQuery. But you correct me about the "stringifying" the booleans at least, so thanks :)